# Check if a target exists dynamically using Nant?

Tags: nant

According to the [Nant documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/target.exists.html), you can check if a target exists using the target::exists function.

```
Execute target "clean", if it exists.

<if test="${target::exists('clean')}">
<call target="clean" />
</if>
```

I've tried passing in the name of the target as a property and it doesn't seem to work.

Nant doesn't throw an error, but neither does it return true, when it should.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is this:

```
<property name="cleanTarget" value="${someothervariables}"/>

<if test="${target::exists('${cleanTarget}')}">
<call target="${cleanTarget}" />
</if>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out, my syntax was wrong.

The correct way would be:

```
<property name="cleanTarget" value="${someothervariables}"/>

<if test="${target::exists(cleanTarget)}">
<call target="${cleanTarget}" />
</if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it to:

```
<property name="cleanTarget" value="${someothervariables}"/>

<call target="${cleanTarget}" if="${target::exists(cleanTarget)}" />
```